# Have a Malformed Sources.List line and Don't Know How to Correct It

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, tor

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. I tried about 4 different commands to install Tor browser and the first 3 failed. Finally I found step-by-step instructions from HowToGeek.com and they worked perfectly.

The problem seems to be that one of my botched installation attempts messed up my list file. The error message I get when I try to install, reinstall or remove ANYTHING, including ubuntu-software (which does not launch at all), is:

```
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor-project.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I read many of these Q&A's and managed to find the actual line that is corrupted. The two lines read:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal main
deb [arch=amd64] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org  main
```

How do I know what to change line 2 to? I thought maybe the issue was just an extra space between .org and main that I can see in the code but doesn't show up in the HTML above, but I changed it and still could not apt update.

Is it possible to just delete both lines since Tor itself is working perfectly already?

Comment: Remove the 2nd line.

Comment: Thanks, Organic Marble! sudo apt update now works.

Comment: New error message:<br>Get:39 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease [2,812 B]                                   
Err:39 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease                                             
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Then,                                                                                
W: GPG error: https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
E: The repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys PUBKEY` where PUBKEY is the long alphanumeric string from the error message

Comment: Is this just for reference or should I copy and run in terminal (along with the long alphanumeric string)? Thanks.

Comment: That's how to fix it.

Comment: Code ran with one error message.
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
[sudo] password for k: 
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.4zLgABS2Su/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
gpg: "PUBKEY" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: key EE8CBC9E886DDD89: public key "deb.torproject.org archive signing key" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Should I not have typed in the term PUBKEY but only the string of characters? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. replace the word PUBKEY with the long alphanumeric string from the error message